# Hadoop Standalone Cluster Pyspark Load CSV file does not Exist(hdfs://home/usr/filepath.csv)

Tags: csv, hadoop, pyspark

```
 df = spark.read.csv('/home/hadoop/observations_temp.csv, header=True)
```

When I run the script raises the following error message:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://home/anmol/SnapShot.cvs
```

Comment: are you reading from HDFS or from local files?

Comment: from hdfs://usr/hadoopusr

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a typo in your path, it's `cvs` instead of `csv`. This should work

```py
df = spark.read.csv('hdfs://home/anmol/SnapShot.csv')
```